# Is there anyway to cosmetically repair a crack in a sink?

Tags: sink

This is my bathroom sink. When we purchased the house we didn't notice the crack.
[image: sink crack]
Short of replacing the porcelain basin, is there something that I can do to hide the crack and also potentially prevent the crack from getting larger?

Comment: The epoxy to fill such a crack is not cheap. A DIYer would not normally have the skill required to fill the crack with epoxy or other permanent filler to give a cosmetically acceptable repair. The crack would or could continue to propagate. The cost and difficulty argue against repairing, so the most appropriate action is to replace the basin.

Comment: Replacement is the only practical (and least cost) option for a dependable repair.